# AdMob Test Ads Error

Tags: sprite-kit, admob

I am ready to release a game that uses Admob banner ads however the ads do not show up. The log says `<Google> Advertising tracking may be disabled. To get test ads on this device, enable advertising tracking.` But this identical code has worked for my other games(appId is correct). Im not sure why this is or how to fix it. I did not have to change any privacy settings for my other app.

Note: i am aware of the other similar questions however they do not answer my problem. If I have to change the privacy settings, then my users will and I dont want that. Please let me know what you think. Thanks

Swift 2 Xcode SpriteKit

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this message because you've limited ad tracking inside of Settings -> Privacy -> Advertising.
to read [this manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting)